# Prove $\text{Inn}(\mathbb{Q_8}) \cong \mathbb{Q_8}/ Z(\mathbb{Q_8})$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-isomorphism, automorphism-group

I found on wikipedia somewhere that $\text{Inn}(\mathbb{Q_8}) \cong \mathbb{Q_8}/ Z(\mathbb{Q_8})$ but I don't know how to prove that their orders are equal.

---

Also, note: $Z(\mathbb{Q_8}) = \{-1,1\}$ so $| \mathbb{Q_8}/ Z(\mathbb{Q_8}) |= \frac{| \mathbb{Q_8}|}{2} = 8/2=4$

---

How do I prove $|\text{Inn}(\mathbb{Q_8}) | = 4$?

---

Note: $\mathbb{Q_8}$ is the quaternion group = $\{-1, 1, -i, i, -j, j, -k, k\}$

Comment: $\mathrm{Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G)$ holds for all groups $G$. Is $\mathbb{Q}_8$ supposed to be the Quaternion group?

Comment: The inner isomorphism group of **any** group $G$ is isomorphic to $G/Z(G)$.

Comment: @Thorgott, yes it is the quaternion group {-1, 1, -i, i -j, j, -k, k}

Comment: I would recommend trying to understand $\mathrm{Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G)$ in general before thinking about this specific case. Also, note that the equality of the orders is not enough to deduce isomorphy.

Comment: Please don't shout!

Comment: @Thorgott You are correct. Equal orders is not enough to prove isomorphy, but in this case, I know what I've written above is true. How do I find the elements of Inn(Q8), or rather how do I determine the order of Inn(Q8)?

Comment: @AnginaSeng It's a formatting error from adding a line of dashes to make a divider but without enough line breaks before and after. It's easily remedied, especially by someone with 130k reputation, while a new user with 23 reputation might not know the ins and outs of our markdown.

Comment: The easiest way is to prove the general fact $\mathrm{Inn}(G)\cong G/Z(G)$, which is a nice consequence of the first isomorphism theorem. I don't see a quick way of calculating the order without this, you may just have to compute the elements explicitly, but that's unnecessarily tedious

Comment: @Arthur I did edit it, but the OP reverted the edits :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have, in general, that the canonical homomorphism $G\to \operatorname{Inn}(G)$

1. is surjective
2. has $Z(G)$ as kernel

Both of these are nice exercises to work through. And I don't think there is an easier way to show that the orders of $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ and $G/Z(G)$ are equal than to use these two facts to show that they are, in fact, isomorphic.

Comment: does this mean that since you said $Z(\mathbb{Q_8}) = ker \mathbb{Q_8}$ that this means $Z(\mathbb{Q_8}) = \{1\} \neq \{-1, 1\}$?

Comment: @ChaseReiter What do you mean by $\ker \Bbb Q_8$?

Comment: Because when you compose -1 with x, x isn't left alone. x becomes -x. Therefore, -1 is not in the kernel

Comment: All I'm asking is if my $Z(\mathbb{Q_8})$ in my post is correct

Comment: @ChaseReiter The element of $\operatorname{Inn}(\Bbb Q_8)$ that comes from $-1$ is _not_ "multiply by $-1$". It is "conjugate by $-1$". Beecause that's what the inner homomorphisms are. And conjugating by $-1$ does nothing. So it is indeed in the kernel of this canonical map.

Comment: Lol, looking back at it $ker \mathbb{Q_8}$ doesn't make any sense. Idk, I'm retarded

Comment: @ChaseReiter No worries. Brain farts happen.